# How do I fix this Illegal break statement?

Tags: javascript

I have a loop running through every radio. Based on the radio selected, the user earns a certain amount of points to their score. Once that score is 8 or higher, i have a display box that I want to show. Problem is I only want it to display once, not for ever single instance of a score >= 8.

```
for (var i = 0; i < allRadiosArr.length; i++) {
  allRadiosArr[i].addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
    totalScoreMain = 0;
    let checkedRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    checkedRadios.forEach(function(checkedRadio){
      totalScoreMain += parseInt(checkedRadio.getAttribute('value'));
    });
    if (totalScoreMain >= 8) {
      referralModalMain.style.display = 'block';
      break;
    }
  });

  closeButtonMain.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  referralModalMain.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

Comment: Your `break;` statement is inside the event listener; it doesn't make any sense to break from the loop from inside the handler because the handler won't be called until later, long after the loop is finished.

Comment: You don't have to `break;`. Use a flag, e.g. `let shown = true`, then set that to `false` when you show the modal the first time, and don't show it again.

Comment: Just use a flag to determine whether the box has been shown already. Once you show it, set the flag to `true`, then join the if only as long as the flag is false; this will prevent the dialog to spawn more than once. Other than that, just remove that `break` here, it's not needed and won't make any benefit.

Comment: Just a side note,  it looks like you can use the same event handler for every checkbox.  Here you are creating a unique function for every radio button, when 1 would suffice.  Also your closeButtonMain event handling is going to get assigned multiple times, as your doing inside your loop.  IOW: Your wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `break;`. Use a flag, e.g. `let modalShown = false`, then set that to `true` when you show the modal the first time, and don't show it again.

```
let modalShown = false;
for (var i = 0; i < allRadiosArr.length; i++) {
  allRadiosArr[i].addEventListener('change', (e)=>{
    totalScoreMain = 0;
    let checkedRadios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
    checkedRadios.forEach(function(checkedRadio){
      totalScoreMain += parseInt(checkedRadio.getAttribute('value'));
    });
    if (!modalShown && totalScoreMain >= 8) {
      referralModalMain.style.display = 'block';
      modalShown = true;
    }
  });

  closeButtonMain.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    referralModalMain.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

*Edit: Please make sure you read and understood all the helpful comments you received under your question, because they are more valuable than my simple answer and contain important advices.*